# Symbolic differentiation

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Well, I know, for a normal case, if I define

```
syms x,y
K = f(x,y)
```

as an explicit expression on `x` and `y`, we can do `diff(K, x)` or `diff(K, y)` to obtain what we want.

But right now, if I have another function

```
J = g(K)
```

And I want to do

```
diff(J, K)
```

then error occurs as:

> 'The second argument must be a variable or a non negative integer specifying the number of differentiations.'

So, in a nutshell, how to solve this kind of 'chained expression differentiation'? (Sorry for this ambiguous description.)

Comment: Hi Zejiang, could you provide a small code example to reproduce the error?

Comment: The easy way is to also define K as a symbolic expression as another  'root variable'.

Answer (score 0):

According to the diff function in Matlab,

> The first argument should be the function you want to differentiate
>   and the remaining arguments must be either the symbolic variables or a
>   non-negative number which represents the number of differentiation.

So, the error.

```
The second argument must be a variable or a non negative integer specifying the number of differentiations.
```

In the code `diff(J, K)` is saying that K is a symbolic variable to the Matlab but in actual case, K is an expression in the terms of x and y. So, this is the reason why Matlab is throwing that error.

So if you want to differentiate a chained function with variables x, y then you need to mention each symbolic variables explicitly within the diff() function whenever you want to differentiate that expression. The code to do so is below.

```
% define the symbolic functions
% as f(x,y) and g(K)
syms f(x,y) g(K)

% create the functions
K = f(x,y)
J = g(K)

% differentiate the functions with
% respect to x and y respectively.
% ------------------------
% differentiate w.r.t x
diff_K_x = diff(K, x)
% differentiate w.r.t y
diff_K_y = diff(K, y)
% -----------------------

% differentiate the function J with respect to x and y both
diff_K_xy = diff(J,x,y)
```